# How to create a websocket in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, java-websocket

I need help understanding how to create a websocket in GWT. Basically I need to look into creating a system for push notifications, I tried looking into Atmosphere for that but I currently have my workspace setup not using maven, and all the tutorials have maven in mind. I tried to download and manually import the jars needed but still having issues.

I was wondering if there are tutorials for creating a websocket on the server side and having the client listen to it. I am currently using GWT 2.8 for my environment setup.

Any help or tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Elemental has a nice api for creating web sockets. This example isn't using Websockets, but shows how to wire up elemental fileReader api. https://gist.github.com/branflake2267/180b69b9a29987214643f62fb279151f and the javadoc http://docs.sencha.com/gxt/4.x/javadoc/gwt-2.8.0/gwt-elemental-2.8.0/index.html?overview-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can write a client ws with JSNI like this:

```
public class SomeClassSingleton{

    private static SomeClassSingleton instance;
    public static SomeClassSingleton  getInstance(){
        .
        .
        .
        return instance;
    }

    private native void connectionWS()/*-{  

    // connection variable
    var connection = new WebSocket('ws://www.endpointwebsocket.com:8888/ws/ws');
    // run connection function
    connect();
        function connect() {
            // open connection
            connection.onopen;

            connection.onerror = function (error) {
                .   
                .
                .
            };

            connection.onmessage = function (e) {
                .
                .
                .
            };

            connection.onopen = function (e) {
                var pa1=@com.something.client.communication.ClientWS::Rol;                  
                var pa2=@com.something.client.communication.ClientWS::channel;
                var pa3=@com.something.client.communication.ClientWS::allowRead;
                var pa4=@com.something.client.communication.ClientWS::allorMod;
                var jsonp= JSON.stringify({ "pC":["false",pa1,pa2,pa3,pa4]});
                connection.send(jsonp);
            }

            connection.onclose = function (e) {
                .
                .
                .
            }
        }
}-*/;
}
```

Or, if you want a gwt push system only, see gwteventservice:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.novanic.gwteventservice/gwteventservice

Regards